# How to link my facebook app to the app's facebook page (created separately)

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

Facebook did not let me create the app from the app developers "contact" section because it has some issue with its name (apparently a known issue). So, I created a page for the app through the page generator - with a capital letter as a first letter.
How do I now link the two together, so the page points to the app?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [Like Box social plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

have a look at similar plugins if it is not the exact thing you want